# I'm trying to get name from another table, where is FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE RecipeMaterial(
        recipe INT,
        material INT,
        howMuch INT,
        unit STRING,
CONSTRAINT RecipeMaterial_Recipe_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (recipe)
        REFERENCES Recipe (id)
CONSTRAINT RecipeMaterial_Material_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (material)
        REFERENCES Material (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Material(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name TEXT,
unit TEXT,
plusUnit TEXT,
nowHave INTEGER,
min INTEGER
);
```

I also have a Recipe table, but that doesn't counts here.
I want to insert into a TableView, but instead of Material id, I want to get it's name value from the Material table. So I'm selecting its ID, but I want to get it's name by ID and get it into the TableView

For example:

Instead of

```
RecipeMaterial:
  recipe: 5;
  material: 10;
  howMuch: 10;
  unit: tablespoon
```

I want:

```
RecipeMaterial:
  recipe: 5;
  material: (name of material with ID 10);
  how much: 10;
  unit: tablespoon;
```

I tried INNER JOIN, But it doesn't work, is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple join to select data from to tables. For details please have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

In your case the solution should be:

```
select
 rm.recipe,
 m.name,
 rm.howMuch,
 rm.unit
from
 RecipeMaterial rm,
 Material m
where 
rm.material = m.id
```